# Removing the "Open in new window" context menu item without disabling the Win+E shortcut

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, context-menu

On Windows 7, the *Open in new window* context menu item for folders can be removed from the right-click context menu by adding a `LegacyDisable` value to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\opennewwindow
```

By default, however, disabling the key in this way disables Windows 7's <kbd>Win+E</kbd> shortcut to opening an Explorer window. It's also possible that it disables other Windows shortcuts.

**How can I disable the** `opennewwindow` **registry key without disabling the** <kbd>Win+E</kbd> **shortcut?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this key:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\opennewwindow]
"ProgrammaticAccessOnly"=""
```