# ctrl+shift+n creates new shortcut instead of a folder

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, regedit

I was removing some items from my context menu by deleting registry keys and I think I messed up something and now I cant create a new folder using keyboard shortcut or by going to new and new folder.. So if there is any key which I can add in registry so that I can create new folder again.

Comment: Hi, may I ask what specific registry key you deleted?

Comment: Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/1242831/removing-the-open-in-new-window-context-menu-item-without-disabling-the-wine